# how to fetch the parent of a component?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am appending lists and a `button` : **New Button** to a page when an add `button` is clicked. But what i want is that when the "New button" is clicked, a variable should be printed to the parent (the list which the "New Button" is in).

How can i achieve this?

The code :

```
.boardcanvas
    {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    }
#board
    {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding-right: 56px;  
    background-color: rgb(95, 130, 131);
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;

    }
.listwrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 270px;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: rgb(10, 73, 75);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:0;
}
.controls{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Html:

```
   <body class = "boardcanvas">
        <div id="board">
            <div class = "controls">
                <button onclick="addme()">
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>

    <div class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper" style="display:none">
        <ul id ="selected"   style ="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;" 
            class ="consort">
            <div id ="transparent">
                    <button onclick ="new1()">New button</button>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
     <a id = "addlist" onclick ="change()" style ="color:inherit" href="#">
                Add a List...
        </a>
 </body>
```

JQuery:

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
    $('.controls').hide();
     function change()
        {   $('#addlist').replaceWith('<div class = "controls"><button 
            onclick="addme()">Add'+
                '</button></div>');

        }   

 function addme()
  {   
  $('#board').append('<div class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper">'+
            '<ul id ="selected"   style ="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: 
   none;" class ="consort">'+
                '<div id ="transparent">'+
                '<button onclick ="new1()">New button</button>'+ 
                '</div>'+
            '</ul></div>');
  $('.controls').appendTo('#board');

   }

function new1(){
    $("#listwrapper").append("a");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "a variable should be printed to the parent"?

Comment: means if i click `add` 5 times, i have 5  divs aka`listwrappers` each with its own `New Button`. Now if I click `New Button`, a letter/variable A should be appended but only to the `listwrapper` that the New button is in and not to some other div/`listwrapper`.

Comment: when you are adding New Button why are you having same id listWrapper to the div? Keep different id with all the listWrapper

Comment: how can i give a different id to every `listwrapper` that is created?

Comment: keep a global counter for the no. of new button added and append that with id listWrapper.

Comment: i added a  `counter` and then gave it to the `new1()` function like this: `$("#listwrapper"+counter).append("a"); ` , where the counter values are correct but still the variable is not getting appended to its parent when the `new button` is clicked

Comment: Add jsFiddle with this change. I will check

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/vjxzx0dz/  its not running in jsfiddle but it might run in yours.

Comment: Rather *bind* that click event to the element itself so that you can use `this` to reference it's parent using the jQuery method `.parents('.listwrapper')`, once you have the right element referenced you can chain the `.append()` method to append whatever you need to, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/vjxzx0dz/3/ ("*a*" will append to the parent element (`.listwrapper`) of the `button` clicked)

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Are you referring to the suggestion I've mentioned above with the JSFiddle demonstration? If that is the case, I'd like to add it as an official answer you can accept.

Comment: yes i was referring to the suggestion that you had shown

Comment: I've added an answer that expands on the suggested approach and touches on *event delegation*. Remember to use the *@* symbol to mention a user in your comments so that they are notified (you don't need to do this in comments attached to their own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather *bind* that click event to the element itself so that you can use this to reference it's parent using the jQuery method `.parents()`<sup>[Ref - jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)</sup>, e.g: `.parents('.listwrapper')`.

Once you have the right element referenced you can chain the `.append()` method to append whatever you need to, .eg:

```
$('#board').on('click', '.add-new-button', function(){
  $(this).parents('.listwrapper').append("a");
});
```

*Note:*

Since the element is dynamically generated, and may not be present on page load to directly bind the event to, *delegate*<sup>[Ref - jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)</sup> the event handler to the closest containing element that is present on page load, e.g: `#board`, then reference the event target, or triggered element, as a *selector* parameter, e.g: `.add-new-button`.

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`.** To
>   ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts
>   after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside
>   a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to
>   attach event handlers.
>
> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Ref: [Direct and delegated events - .on() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$('.controls').hide();

function change() {
  $('#addlist').replaceWith('<div class="controls"><button onclick="addme()">Add</button></div>');
}

function addme() {
  $('#board').append('<div class="listwrapper" id="listwrapper">' +
    '<ul id="selected" style="margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;" class="consort ">' +
    '<div id="transparent">' +
    '<button class="add-new-button">New button</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>');
  $('.controls').appendTo('#board');
}

$('#board').on('click', '.add-new-button', function(){
  $(this).parents('.listwrapper').append("a");
});
```

```css
.boardcanvas {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#board {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-right: 56px;
  background-color: rgb(95, 130, 131);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.listwrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 270px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: rgb(10, 73, 75);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.controls {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="boardcanvas">
  <div id="board">
    <div class="controls">
      <button onclick="addme()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div class="listwrapper" id="listwrapper" style="display:none">
      <ul id="selected" style="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;" class="consort">
        <div id="transparent">
          <button class="add-new-button">New button</button>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a id="addlist" onclick="change()" style="color:inherit" href="#">Add a List...</a>
</body>
```

*[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjxzx0dz/3/)*

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel ="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<a href="blog/2015/08/jquery-bootstrap-icons.download.html" data-icon="download-alt"></a>
<script>
$('.controls').hide();
function change()
{   $('#addlist').replaceWith('<div class = "controls"><button onclick="addme()">Add'+
                    '</button></div>');
    
}   
var counter =0;
    function addme()
    {  counter++;
      $('#board').append('<div class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper'+counter +'">'+
                '<ul id ="selected"   style ="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;" class ="consort">'+
                    '<div id ="transparent">'+
                    '<button onclick ="new1()">New button</button>'+ 
                    '</div>'+
                '</ul></div>');
        $('.controls').appendTo('#board');
    
    }

    function new1(){
        $( event.target ).closest( ".listwrapper" ).append("a");
        //$("#listwrapper"+counter-1)
        //alert(counter);
    }
</script>
<body class = "boardcanvas">
    <div id="board">
            <div class = "controls">
                    <button onclick="addme()">
                        Add
                    </button>
            </div>
          
        <div class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper" style="display:none">
            <ul id ="selected"   style ="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;" class ="consort">
                <div id ="transparent">
                        <button onclick ="new1()">New button</button>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
       
    </div>
      <a id = "addlist" onclick ="change()" style ="color:inherit" href="#">
                    Add a List...
            </a>
</body>
```

Check this I have updated the code you were using.

Comment: @sanjana Check this if it helps. I have updated the code. Now you can see the alert coming up.

Comment: it works perfectly but if i have say 3 divs, and i click on the `new button` on the 2nd div, it adds the variable `a` to the most recent div which is the 3rd one. It should add `a` to the 2nd one instead. How can i read the id of the parent in this situation?